# Delphi - mORMot : Installation went wrong. Automated Test Error on UTF8 test! How do I Fix this?

Tags: unit-testing, delphi, mormot

I added mORMot folders to Delphi's Library and tested if it works properly by running TestSQL3 in Folder SQLite3. And it shows Error at UTF8

!  - UTF8: 14,000 / 1,099,792 FAILED  1.15s

How do I fix this? Please Help!! Thank you in advance.

> Synopse mORMot Framework Automated tests
>
> ---
>
> 1. Synopse libraries
>
> 1.1. Low level common:
>
> - System copy record: 162 assertions passed  108us
> - TRawUTF8List: 190,172 assertions passed  61.62ms
> - TDynArray: 1,092,815 assertions passed  137.96ms
> - TDynArrayHashed: 1,599,067 assertions passed  1.09s
> - TSynDictionary: 139,850 assertions passed  324.01ms
> - TSynQueue: 6,541,501 assertions passed  215.78ms
> - TObjectListHashed: 2,996,100 assertions passed  1.49s
> - TObjectListSorted: 79,912 assertions passed  51.59ms
> - TSynNameValue: 40,032 assertions passed  5.54ms
> - TRawUTF8Interning: 2,000,013 assertions passed  122.39ms
>   500000 interning 8 KB in 40.91ms i.e. 12,219,262/s, aver. 0us, 186.4 MB/s
>   500000 direct 7.6 MB in 12.76ms i.e. 39,175,742/s, aver. 0us, 597.7 MB/s
> - TObjectDynArrayWrapper: 167,501 assertions passed  13.25ms
> - TObjArray: 3,230 assertions passed  1.72ms
> - Custom RTL: 77,552 assertions passed  1s
>   FillChar in 30.56ms, 12.7 GB/s
>   Move in 4.51ms, 3.4 GB/s
>   small Move in 5.86ms, 3.7 GB/s
>   big Move in 106.81ms, 3.6 GB/s
>   FillCharFast [] in 33.54ms, 11.5 GB/s
>   MoveFast [] in 3.61ms, 4.3 GB/s
>   small MoveFast [] in 5.76ms, 3.8 GB/s
>   big MoveFast [] in 105.27ms, 3.7 GB/s
> - Fast string compare: 71 assertions passed  268us
> - IdemPropName: 216 assertions passed  207us
> - Url encoding: 152 assertions passed  1.08ms
> - GUID: 10,007 assertions passed  2.75ms
> - ParseCommandArguments: 232 assertions passed  370us
> - IsMatch: 4,250 assertions passed  2.27ms
> - TExprParserMatch: 140 assertions passed  663us
> - Soundex: 35 assertions passed  518us
> - Numerical conversions: 2,545,159 assertions passed  351.35ms
>   100000 FloatToText  in 16.49ms i.e. 6,062,443/s, aver. 0us, 109.9 MB/s
>   100000 str  in 23.31ms i.e. 4,290,004/s, aver. 0us, 94 MB/s
>   100000 DoubleToShort  in 18.31ms i.e. 5,460,899/s, aver. 0us, 99 MB/s
> - Integers: 33,860 assertions passed  48.08ms
> - crc32c: 290,087 assertions passed  80.93ms
>   pas 286.7 MB/s fast 2.4 GB/s sse42 4.1 GB/s
> - Random32: 201,002 assertions passed  25.81ms
> - Bloom filters: 2,010,072 assertions passed  128.92ms
> - DeltaCompress: 87 assertions passed  6.38ms
> - Curr 64: 20,056 assertions passed  1.83ms
> - CamelCase: 11 assertions passed  116us
> - Bits: 22,985 assertions passed  14.47ms
> - Ini files: 7,028 assertions passed  188.97ms !  - UTF8: 14,000 / 1,099,792 FAILED  1.15s
> - Url decoding: 1,101 assertions passed  561us
> - Baudot code: 10,007 assertions passed  21.87ms
> - Iso 8601 date and time: 200,831 assertions passed  16.80ms
> - Time zones: 408 assertions passed  212.13ms
> - Mime types: 30 assertions passed  651us
> - Quick select: 4,015 assertions passed  124.33ms
> - TSynTable: 875 assertions passed  2.34ms
> - TSynCache: 404 assertions passed  404us
> - TSynFilter: 1,005 assertions passed  2.57ms
> - TSynValidate: 677 assertions passed  774us
> - TSynLogFile: 49 assertions passed  977us
> - TSynUniqueIdentifier: 1,300,002 assertions passed  515.62ms   Total failed: 14,000 / 22,692,553  - Low level common FAILED  7.45s
>
> Windows 10 64bit (10.0.18362) (cp874)
> 8 x Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-9300H CPU @ 2.40GHz (x86) Using mORMot 1.18.6102
> TSQLite3LibraryStatic 3.32.3 with internal MM Generated with: Delphi 10.3 Rio 32 bit compiler
>
> Time elapsed for all tests: 2m29 Performed 2020-08-06 23:58:11 by
> LENOVO on LAPTOP-BED954TL
>
> Total assertions failed for all test suits:  14,000 / 45,919,717 !
> Some tests FAILED: please correct the code.
>
> Done - Press ENTER to Exit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a restriction with the regression tests.

As your output states:

```
Windows 10 64bit (10.0.18362) (cp874)
```

you are using a system with a [Code Page 874](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-11).

During some of the tests, some UTF-8 to WinAnsi - aka [code page 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) - are performed via the `AnsiString` type, and some characters are likely to be missing with your own code page.

Therefore some test failure are reported.

This is a false positive error, due to some restriction of the current tests. I will try to avoid such issue in the future.

If you can compile `TestSQL3` then it is very likely that *your installation is correct*, and it will work as expected with internal UTF-8 content (mORMot works internally with UTF-8 JSON to avoid unneeded conversions), and regular VCL `string` type, which is UTF-16, will safely be available via  `UTF8ToString/StringToUTF8()` functions.